# will RAM from a mid-2011 MacBook Pro work in an early 2011 iMac?

Tags: macbook-pro, imac, memory

Will RAM from a mid-2011 MBP work in an early 2011 iMac (and vice-versa)? Both are listed as 1333 MHz PC3-10600 DDR3.

I have 16 GB (2x8GB) in the MacBook Pro, and 12 GB (2x4GB + 2x8GB) in the iMac.

I want to swap the MacBook Pro's RAM with the 2x4B set in the iMac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory for the MacBook Pro 8,1; 8,2 and 8,3 is the same as for the iMac 12,1 and 12,2.

Just as a point of clarity, the models possible are:

Early 2011 MacBook Pro
Late 2011 MacBook Pro

Mid 2011 iMac
Late 2011 iMac

Comment: I also have a Mac Mini (mid 2011, 2.3Ghz i5) from the same era. Also compatible?

Comment: The Mid 2011 Macmini5,2 features 2 - 204-pin PC-10600 (1333 MHz) DDR3 SO-DIMM. While Apple officially states max. 8GB, it can actually happily support 16GB. If you fully populate it with max memory, you'll likely notice quite a nice improvement in performance.

Also, for all the information you could want on pretty much any Apple product, check out Mactracker from the App Store. it's available on both OS X and iOS. Free. Excellent app.